# Gson stream closing

Tags: java, json, stream, gson, coding-efficiency

Does the stream close when you use something like:

```
gson.toJson(obj, new FileWriter("C:\\fileName.json"));
```

or is it better to to this:

```
        try (Reader reader = new FileReader("c:\\test\\staff.json")) {

            // Convert JSON File to Java Object
            Staff staff = gson.fromJson(reader, Staff.class);

            // print staff 
            System.out.println(staff);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I know the try block closes the stream, but does ths first example also close the stream?

Code taken from 
[Mkyong](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-parse-json-with-gson/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the stream close when you use something like:
>
> ```java
> gson.toJson(obj, new FileWriter("C:\\fileName.json"));
> ```

It does not. You should close it using try-with-resources, or a try-catch-finally block.

---

Since JDK 7, the preferred way to close an AutoClosable is to use try-with-resources (like in your second snippet):

```java
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\fileName.json")) {
    gson.toJson(obj, writer);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you could call `close()` using a try-catch-finally block:

```java
FileWriter writer = null;
try {
    writer = new FileWriter("C:\\fileName.json");
    gson.toJson(obj, writer);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (writer != null) {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

`FileWriter` implements `AutoClosable` so it needs to be closed. Not naming the variable will not close it automatically.

Comment: So its best to use the second way?

Comment: @gike yes, it is better. Would prevent memory leaks and prevent locking of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your response